# Como converter vídeo com php sem usar ffmpeg?

Tags: php

Queria saber se existe alguma forma de fazer a conversão de vídeos no PHP sem o uso do *ffmpeg*, pois minha hospedagem não permite instalar nada.

Caso não tenha como, alguém sabe de alguma API que faça a conversão de videos e áudios gratuitamente. Algo como

```
http://[host da api]/convert?target=[url para arquivo]&output=[nome do arquivo saída]
```

Isso por GET ou então por POST com o AJAX ou cURL.

Comment: Seu servidor não permite instalar ffmpeg? Porque se não permite isso então dificilmente você vai conseguir usar alguma alternativa. Que tal subir para o YouTube e usar a API para pegar o feed de vídeos e colocar em um player customizado?

Comment: Meu servidor não aceita a instalação do ffmpeg nem através dos sources.

A ideia é justamente se livrar do vídeo, quero somente o áudio dele. A ideia geral é extrair o vídeo do youtube o que está ok no servidor local e remoto, e depois pegar o vídeo e converte-lo para mp3. Alguns sites já fazem isso, como por exemplo http://tubget.com/.

Comment: Infelizmente não conheço nenhum serviço assim, vou editar a pergunta por que o teu problema é especifico para áudio. Perguntas devem sempre ser o mais objetivas possiveis.

Comment: Estamos discutindo esta pergunta e resposta no *META*: [Perguntas o qual a resposta são software de terceiros estão no escopo?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4880/3635)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pesquisando a única que encontrei que parece satisfatória foi http://www.online-convert.com, segue links:

### Breve documentação:

- http://www.online-convert.com/developer
- http://api.online-convert.com

### PHP:

- [Repositório](https://github.com/onlineconvert/onlineconvert-api-sdk-php)
- [Instalação packagist (composer)](https://packagist.org/packages/qaamgo/onlineconvert-api-sdk)

### Java

- [Repositório](https://github.com/onlineconvert/onlineconvert-api-sdk-java)
- [JAR](https://github.com/onlineconvert/onlineconvert-api-sdk-java/tree/master/releases)

### Limitações da versão gratuita

- Limite máximo de 30 conversões por dia (a cada 24 horas)
- Limite máximo de upload por arquivo é de 100 Megabytes

*(Realmente para algo free isto me surpreendeu)*

### Como usar

O processo é feito por *REST* usando um *JSON* assim:

```
POST /jobs HTTP/1.1
Host: https://api2.online-convert.com
X-Oc-Api-Key: <sua chave da API key deve vir aqui>
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "input": [{
        "type": "remote",
        "source": "http:\/\/site\/arquivo"
    }],
    "conversion": [{
        "target": "wav"
    }]
}
```

Troque `<sua chave da API key deve vir aqui>` pela sua chave de acesso (é necessário se cadastrar em http://www.online-convert.com)

Se quiser usar as classes prontas para PHP faça assim (usando o [onlineconvert-api-sdk-php](https://github.com/onlineconvert/onlineconvert-api-sdk-php)):

```
<?php
define('API_KEY', 'sua chave da API key deve vir aqui');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$config = new \OnlineConvert\Configuration();
$config->setApiKey('main', API_KEY);
$client = new \OnlineConvert\Client\OnlineConvertClient($config, 'main');
$syncApi = new \OnlineConvert\Api($client);
```

O exemplo é sync, mas também pode ser async:

```
$asyncApi = new \OnlineConvert\Api($client, true);
```

Note que ele usa autoload, pois a instalação é feita por `composer`, ou seja se quiser fazer "manualmente" vai ser um pouco trabalhoso pois é necessário estudar e entender o `composer` e o `autoload`.