# PHP Converter vídeo via API

Tags: php

Existe alguma API/Classe em PHP que faz conversão de arquivos?

Neste caso as conversões seriam:

- AVI para WEBM
- MP4 para WEBM
- WEBM para MP4

Comment: Pode usar [esta solução](http://ffmpeg.org/) para conversões do lado do servidor.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesses links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682393/upload-a-video-via-php-and-encode-to-mp4-and-or-webm-on-the-server e 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954845/how-to-create-a-webm-video-file

Comment: Uma classe PHP não vai conseguir fazer isso sozinho, vai ser necessário coisas como FFMPEG, mas isto é complicado de instalar no teu servidor. Todavia no titulo você escreveu API, apesar de API ter vários significados, suponho que você possa estar se referendo a um "serviço", neste caso tente esta resposta que formulei No titulo você diz via API, suponho que esta resposta possa lhe ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113600/3635