# Reduzir o tamanho de um vídeo com PHP

Tags: php

Estou criando um site onde o usuário poderá postar imagens e vídeos. O usuário poderá colocar um vídeo com até 10MB inicialmente, mas eu queria reduzir isso, em meu site, para 1MB ou menos (qualquer redução para mim está ótimo, mas quanto mais melhor rsrs). Eu fiz um sistema de redimensionamento com as imagens para reduzir seu peso, mas com vídeo eu não sei se é possível fazer. Observei que o Youtube tem um sistema que reduz o peso dos vídeos e queria fazer algo parecido, mas não sei se é possível em minha atual situação. Pesquisei, mas não vi nada que pudesse me ajudar em relação a isso.

Comment: Luizinho se não tiver como instalar ffmpeg no teu servidor existe uma alternativa que é um serviço online: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113600/3635 espero que ajude

Comment: Opa, valeu Guillerme! Mas acredito que de para instalar o ffmpeg no meu servidor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não existe nada assim com PHP nativo, nenhum site usa a linguagem propriamente dita para fazer o processo, o que usam são softwares próprio para conversão instalados no servidor, o software que provavelmente vai resolver o seu problema é o `ffmpeg`

Você terá que instalar ele no teu servidor, se tiver acesso via SSH talvez seja possivel, depois de instalado você pode reduzir o tamanho do video para cada dispositivo, por exemplo

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=320:-1" mobile.mp4
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=640:-1" desktop.mp4
```

O valor passado para `-vf`, usa `-1` pois assim mantem o ratio do tamanho do video, no primeiro comando reduz o video para 320 a largura, no segundo reduz para 640 a largura, em ambos a altura será ajustada de maneira equivalente, então você pode executar isto usando PHP assim:

```
function resize_video($width, $input, $output)
{
    $input = escapeshellarg($input);
    $output = escapeshellarg($output);

    exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $input . ' -vf "scale=' . $width . ':-1" ' . $output);
}

resize_video(320, 'caminho-do-video-que-fez-upload.mp4', 'assets/mobile.mp4');

resize_video(640, 'caminho-do-video-que-fez-upload.mp4', 'assets/desktop.mp4');
```

Nos exemplos para desktop usei 640 de largura, mas é só um exemplo, você pode decidir qual tamanho acha melhor, assim conforme o dispositivo do usuário você entrega o video menor ou maior.

---

### Comprimindo ao máximo o video

Uma sugestão da [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20318375/1518921), que o AP testou diferentes parametros, foi o usar `-preset veryslow -crf 28`, provavelmente assim para mobile:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=320:-1" -preset veryslow -crf 28 mobile.mp4
```

E assim para Desktop:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=640:-1" -preset veryslow -crf 28 desktop.mp4
```

---

### Biblioteca PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Como citado pelo Valdeir Psr, você pode usar a biblioteca https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Para usar ela, requer que seu projeto use `composer`, então na pasta do seu projeto, via terminal ou cmd use o comando:

```
composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg
```

Essa biblioteca também requer o ffmpeg instalado, ou seja ela é apenas para facilitar a escrita dos parametros, do meu ponto de vista, para o seu caso especifico ela é um pouco de exagero, já que provavelmente só vai executar um comando simples e sempre o mesmo, mas se o objetivo for usar o ffmpeg para várias coisas, então o PHP-ffmpeg pode vir a calhar, tipo o usuário escolher o tipo de conversão e formato do video, exemplo de uso:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
$video
    ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
    ->save('frame.jpg');
$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'filme.mp4');
```

Se o usuário quiser o formato WebM, trocaria a ultima linha por:

```
->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'filme.webm');
```

---

### CODECs

Vale notar que alguns codecs precisam estar instalados no servidor também para que o FFMPEG funcione para diferentes formatos, nem todos formatos são suportados pelo ffmpeg, para conferir os codecs suportados em seu servidor use o comando:

```
ffmpeg -codecs
```

---

Se não puder instalar ffmpeg em seu site existe uma alternativa de um serviço de terceiros, como respondi em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113600/3635

> leia sobre as limitações da versão gratuita:
>
> - Limite máximo de 30 conversões por dia (a cada 24 horas)
> - Limite máximo de upload por arquivo é de 100 Megabytes

Registre-se em http://www.online-convert.com e então instale a biblioteca via composer:

- https://github.com/onlineconvert/onlineconvert-api-sdk-php

Então um exemplo:

```
<?php
define('API_KEY', 'sua chave da API key deve vir aqui');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$config = new \OnlineConvert\Configuration();
$config->setApiKey('main', API_KEY);
$client = new \OnlineConvert\Client\OnlineConvertClient($config, 'main');
$syncApi = new \OnlineConvert\Api($client);
```

Comment: Ps.: Para complementar, o usuário poderá utilizar a biblioteca [**PHP-FFMpeg**](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr atualizado, grato!